# Reading custom rss feed details using ROME library

Tags: java, rss, feed, rome

By using ROM library, I am able to get the RSS feeds like title,description,publishedDate...etc. But I want to read following RSS feeds:

```
<item>
<photo>http://www.przoom.com/photos/152165_1.jpg</photo>
<title>
Leading Press Release Newswire and Market Research Report Distribution Service Network Celebrates 10 Year Anniversary
</title>
<description>
PRZOOM - Newswire (press release) - 2015/04/20, San Francisco, CA United States - The business news distribution network (PRZOOM.com, NewswireToday.com, and more recently PRTODAY.com) has become the top most used service on a daily basis within the U.S., United Kingdom, France, and Germany
</description>
<link>http://www.przoom.com/news/152165/</link>
<category>Advertising/PPC/Classifieds</category>
</item>
```

I'm unable to read the photo tag here.

Please suggest me on this.Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

[The feed isn't valid](https://validator.w3.org/feed/check.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.przoom.com%2Fxml%2F12%2F):

```
line 13, column 2: Undefined item element: photo (15 occurrences) [help]
  <photo>http://www.przoom.com/photos/152165_1.jpg</photo>
```

And Rome wont provide the `<photo>` tag because it does not belong to the namespace it is in.

Similar issue as this: [get image url of rss with rome library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36743200/get-image-url-of-rss-with-rome-library/36809839#36809839)

EDIT: [by implementing a custom Wirefeed parser, it is possible to save these custom tags](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36854644/989257)